# how to show image in table cell using php

Tags: php

I want to show an image in table cell from database. But this code doesn't work

```
    <tbody>
            <?php
            $i=1;
            foreach($item_list as $item){
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?=$i++; ?></td>
                    <td><img src="<?= $item->image;?>" alt="Not found"></td>
                </tr>
             <?php } ?>
   </tbody>
```

Comment: <img src='"<?= $item->image;?>"'

Try this with single quotes on either side of the double quotes

Comment: What errors are you getting, if any?

Comment: add `$item_list ` result in the question..

Comment: it shows me the path of image.

Comment: @KellyMorrison on the top of the page `print_r($item_list); exit;` add these lines and result add in above question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add Base_url() to the `img` . and give some width and height if you like.

```
<tbody>
            <?php
            $i=1;
            foreach($item_list as $item){
                ?>
                <tr>
                <td><?=$i++; ?></td>
                   <td><img src="<?=base_url().$item->image;?>" alt="Image Not Found" width="100" heigth="100"></td>
                </tr>
             <?php } ?>
   </tbody>
```